# ThreeJs Object Clipping

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to clip one object with another in ThreeJS
I know about plane clipping but I cannot find a way to do this with a specific object.

I have a roof, loaded from an OBJ file. This is a group.
What I want is to use another loaded geometry to cut out or hide a piece from that roof. I'm attaching an image to make it more clear

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify this a little bit more? It's not obvious what's which geometry, if you had a volume in place of that roof, you could do something like this with the stencil buffer.

Comment: To clarify, either way you want to solve this, it seems like a new geometry is required.